# Angular2 : Clear the text box once the value is added

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

How to clear the text once the value is added after clicking the button in angular2 : Following is the template file

```
<div>
  <label>Task:</label> <input #taskNameRef/>
  <button (click)="addTask(taskNameRef.value);">Add</button>
</div>
```

In Compoment i am having the following code for addTask function

```
addTask(name:String): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this._taskService.create(name);
}
```

Note : I am new to angular2.

Comment: I think the way to go here would be to pass the whole `HTMLInputElement` to the `addTask(elem: HTMLInputElement)` function and after you are done working with `elem.value` you could just set it to `null`.

Comment: this worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always wrap your input form inside the form because angular will give you a lot of flexibility to deal with this type of situation.

```
<form #yourFormName="ngForm">
  //Input form code
</form>
```

You have to clear all of the flags imperatively, which you can do by calling the form's reset() method after calling the addTask() method.

```
<button type="button" (click)="addTask(); yourFormName.reset()">Add Task</button>
```

for more detail, please go [Angular Form](https://angular.io/guide/forms)